# Invertibility of the matrix whose elements are the cube of the distance of the indices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, toeplitz-matrices

I would like to prove, for any integer $n>1$, the invertibility of the $n\times n$ matrix $A$ whose elements are given by
$A_{ij}=|i-j|^3$, where $i$ and $j$ are the indices.

To be clearer, for instance if $n=5$ I'm referring to the matrix
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}&0&1&8&27&64\\&1&0&1&8&27\\&8&1&0&1&8\\&27&8&1&0&1\\&64&27&8&1&0\end{bmatrix}\,.$$

Such matrices should indeed be invertible (or at least it seems so looking at the determinant with Mathematica) for any $n>1$ and I do believe that there's should be some easy way to show it. I had some look on invertibility for Toeplitz or Hankel matrices, but I couldn't find any helps there for now.

Comment: Perhaps you can show that the determinant is not divisible by some fixed integer; $n$ and $3$ are possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I guess I've found a way to tackle the problem. Defining $q$ the matrix with elements $q_{ij}=|i-j|$, which is not hard to prove to be invertible, one has
$$q^{-1}\,A\,q^{-1}=M\,,$$
where $M$ is a sparse matrix (nearly tridiagonal), which can be easily shown to be invertible.

Now I'm looking for a smart way to prove that $M$ has such a simple structure. It's not hard to do it by direct calculations but it's a bit tedious and I'm sure there must be some smarter way to do it.

Answer (score -2):

You can think of rank of matrix.

If [mat A ] is to be invertible A has to to have full [rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)).

Comment: It does look obvious that the additional row/column always increases the rank by $1$. But, how to prove it?

Comment: I downvoted. This is not an answer to the question.